My .bib does not produce the arxiv papers but it does with book. What is wrong?
I am using these packages for bibtex
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,hyperpdf,onecolumn]{extarticle}




\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images


%\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

\usepackage{abstract}



\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,  
    citecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
    }









\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
 \usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hepunits,hepnicenames,hepnames,hepparticles,maybemath,braket,cancel, tensor,color,IEEEtrantools}


\usepackage{graphicx, graphics}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}



%references
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum,ifthen} 


\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
%%%bstmods

Mi .bibfile contains this:
@book{Frolov:1418196,
      author        = "Frolov, Valeri P. and Zelnikov, Andrei",
      title         = "{Introduction to black hole physics}",
      publisher     = "Oxford Univ. Press",
      address       = "Oxford",
      year          = "2011",
      url           = "https://cds.cern.ch/record/1418196",
      doi           = "10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199692293.001.0001",
}

@article{frança2014zeroslfunctions,
  title={On the zeros of L-functions}, 
  author={Guilherme França and André LeClair},
  year={2014},
  eprint={1309.7019},
  archivePrefix={arXiv},
  primaryClass={math.NT},
  url={https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.7019}, 
}

@article{frança2014statisticalpropertiesriemannzeros,
  title={Statistical and other properties of Riemann zeros based on an explicit equation for the $n$-th zero on the critical line}, 
  author={Guilherme França and André LeClair},
  year={2014},
  eprint={1307.8395},
  archivePrefix={arXiv},
  primaryClass={math.NT},
  url={https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.8395}, 
}

But the output only produces the @book with doi/title etc
References
[1] Valeri P. Frolov and Andrei Zelnikov. Introduction to black
hole physics. Oxford Univ. Press, Oxford, 2011. doi: 10.1093/
acprof:oso/9780199692293.001.0001. URL https://cds.cern.ch/
record/1418196.
but the arxiv papers with @article etc do not appear in the bibliography. What could I be doing wrong?

you need to show your code if you want someone to say what is wrong with it, edit the question to show a small complete document and a bib file with an @article that you \cite but which does not appear.

you still have not shown an example of your issue, the posted code has no \cite  so would produce no bibliography. Fix your example to remove all unrelated packages such as \usepackage{hepunits,hepnicenames,hepnames, and make it an example of the problem, add a \cite to an entry in a bib file that you reference that does not appear after pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex.

your cite keys should have ascii letters only so c not ç

Ah, is due to that? so I must change it!!! Thank you. That solved my problem!

Off-topic: (a) Instead of providing four separate xxcolor=blue options, you could write allcolors=blue. (b) Since you load graphicx, which loads graphics automatically, there's no need to load graphics explicitly. (c) Absolutely no need for loading epsfig. (d) Don't load packages twice. (e) \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is the default nowadays and may (or should) be omitted. (f) Any reason for not running \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?
